# Получить сумму столбца в переменной pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть код:

```
import pandas as pd
loc1 = *тут нужно получить сумму всех значений в row_1*
table2 = pd.DataFrame( data= [[11,21,10], [10, 30, 20], [11, 41, 30], [50, -100, loc1]  ] , index = ['row_1', 'row_2', 'row_3', 'row_4'], columns = ['B', 'D', 'E'])

table2
```

Как поучить сумму row_1

Comment: как вы собираетесь получить сумму значений ряда, если еще не создали датафрейм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса:

```py
table2.loc['row_4', 'E'] = table2.loc['row_1'].sum()
```